# Cant get this tab to link to the right div when cliked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cant seem to get the first tab (NEWS) to link to the the blog section div..

```
<a href="#new_member_box" class="question1" style="color: #fff">
```

When the page loads, the content is the blog section by default. Then when you click the PRICES tab this section shows, great, but then when you click the NEWS tab again the wrong div appears..

Here is the fiddle to see what I mean
http://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/qfcp3xkd/

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.question1').click(function() {
       $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer1').text());
     });

     $('.question2').click(function() {
       $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer2').text());
     });

     $('.question3').click(function() {
       $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer3').text());
     });

     $('.question4').click(function() {
       $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer4').text());
     });
   });
```

```css
.news {
  font-family: lato-black-webfont;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#latest-news {
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("latestnews-bg.jpg");
  overflow: hidden;
}
#latest-news-content {
  width: 1000px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.new_member_box {} .new_member_box_display {
  float: right;
  width: 614px;
  height: 364px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
}
.question2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content_areas_left_textbody {
  font-family: calibri;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  height: auto;
}
.answer1,
.answer2,
.answer3,
.answer4 {
  display: none;
}
h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tab-box {
  background-color: #1fc4f4;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#last-month {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 870px;
}
```

```html
<div id="latest-news">

  <div style="width:950px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">


    <div style="width:100%; height: 65px">

      <div style=" float: right; width: 662px">

        <div style="background-color: #fff; width: 180px; padding: 16px">
          <h4 class="news">LATEST NEWS</h4>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 400px;">
      <div class="new_member_box">
        <div class="tab-box"><a href="#new_member_box" class="question1" style="color: #fff"><h4 style="color: #fff; font-size: 18px">NEWS</h4></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="new_member_box">
        <div class="tab-box" style="margin-top:6px"><a href="#new_member_box" class="question2">PRICES<img src="http://www.fibufy.co.uk/additional-images/arrow-right.png" style="float: right; margin-top: 4px; margin-right: 6px"></a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>






    <div class="clear" class="question"></div>
    <div class="answer1">
      ARGH NO
    </div>

    <div class="answer2">
      PRICES SECTION
    </div>

    <div class="answer3">
      3
    </div>

    <div class="answer4">
      4
    </div>

    <div class="new_member_box_display" id="question" style="border: 16px solid #1FC4F4; overflow: auto; padding: 25px;">

      Default Blog Text






    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Please somebody help me I have been trying to get this right for two hours :(
thank you.

Comment: Isn't it displaying the right div? I mean, `.question1` element's click handler asks for `.answer1` element's `text()` and it does seem to be getting it. I am not sure if I am seeing what the problem is.

Comment: What div should appear when you click the NEWS tab?

Comment: its showing the correct div that you have put in your js. what div is it you want to show.

Comment: Like other's have said... it's working exactly how it's supposed to.

Comment: hello, its just that the news section (which is the default when the page is loaded) should be shown when it is clicked again. I have tried putting that class into the javascript but not having any luck

Comment: In terms of structure, the approach seems wrong but you could replace `.answer1` to `.news` inside your `.question1.click(...)` line and it would show you what I think you want to see.

Comment: If you want that the news section will show "Default Blog Text", you should replace `.answer1` text to this, instead of "ARGH NO"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the news section to show "Default Blog Text" instead of "ARGH NO" (that is written there for no apparent reason), you should just change `.answer1` text from this:

```
<div class="answer1">
  ARGH NO
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="answer1">
  Default Blog Text
</div>
```